# Eclipse JBoss Tools: Disable content assist (autocompletion) for xhtml files

Tags: eclipse

I would like to disable the content assist feature for xhtml pages that comes with JBoss Tools for eclipse.

Every time I write an EL expression eclipse freezes for about 20-30 seconds while gathering content assist data from my Java code. (It's a large project) Usually I only have to do this once per file, but it's still annoying. I don't really need content assist for EL expressions anyway.

Is there a way to disable content assist only for xhtml files?